# Adding an attribute to a root element using an XSL file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am strugling on something which seems very simple. I want to add an attribute to all element of a certains types on a XML file, using an XSL transformation.

Here is my source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row>
  <Item_1>110000001</Item_1>
  <Item_2>700555608</Item_2>
  <Item_3>1</Item_3>
  <Item_4>2005-12-07</Item_4>
  <age_passage_a>21</age_passage_a>
  <age_passage_m>217</age_passage_m>
  <age_passage_j>6669</age_passage_j>    
  <date_entree>2022-08-08 01:25:00</date_entree>
  <date_naissance>2003-12-07</date_naissance>
</row>
```

The source file may come with multiple `row` elements. In this case, they are surrounded by a `<root>` element.

My XSL file is as follow, and uses this logic:

1. copy all the elements
2. modifiy the `row` elements only (if they don't have an attribute already) and add the attribute.

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row[not(@*)]">
      <xsl:attribute name="tableName">
        <xsl:value-of select="passage"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

The expected XML output should be:

```
<row tableName="passage">
  <Item_1>110000001</Item_1>
  <Item_2>700555608</Item_2>
  <Item_3>1</Item_3>
  ...
</row>
<row tableName="passage">
  <Item_1>110000001</Item_1>
  <Item_2>700555608</Item_2>
  <Item_3>1</Item_3>
  ...
</row>
```

I have some error saying it's not possible to add attribute to a document level element. Which I don't understand because the different elements at the top of the XML have attributes...

Thank you in advance for your help on this little subject!

---

Edit: I'm adding the solution just below. The key in the answer of Martin was to make a copy and applying the template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

 <xsl:param name="TABLE_NAME">passage</xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row[not(@*)]">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="tableName">
       <xsl:value-of select="$TABLE_NAME"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regards,
Eriatolc

Comment: You can shorten your code by using a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element) and [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates): `<row tableName="{$TABLE_NAME}"><xsl:apply-templates/></row>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a shallow copy, add the attribute and process the children:

```
 <xsl:template match="row[not(@*)]">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="tableName">passage</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

That also changes the way to construct the attribute value, your sample suggests you want a constant value.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick answer! I made the shallow copy and it works! Thank you very much. I'm going to edit my question to add the final XSL file.
The attribute value is using a parameter but I didn't want to add complexity to the question.